# Visual Studio Code DLL Develop & Debug

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, visual-studio-code, task

I am developing a c# Excel DLL addin in VS Code Ver 1.42.1. I quickly got an initial C#-only test version working using the VS code editor with only manual Command Line (CL) compiler commands below:

1. csc -t:library -debug -out:Eandin.dll -r:system.dll[....more...] Eaddin.cs
2. csc -t:exe -debug -r:Eaddin.dll -r:system.dll[...more...] Test_Eadin.cs

I am able to successfully manually CL compile this with above commands and then run. But I now need the debugger to debug, test, and validate my app and code. In VS Code, I have created numerous variation of tasks.json and launch.json to automate my manual commands. My *.json files work to build and launch (^shiftB & F5) in VS code. The code runs and produces output, but the debugger does not work.

I think my problem is not sufficiently understanding dotnet c# compilation. Or what?

Can someone please provide guidance on how to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: VSCode/C# extension only has limited support for .NET Framework based applications, https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Desktop-.NET-Framework. You can use Visual Studio instead.

Comment: I started this project in Visual Studio where C# debugging is well supported. But after debugging, I need to create the DLL. Other than creating another Solution/Project I can't figure how to create a dual project solution with 1 project the DLL and the other the C# test console app. And I am having problems getting the DLL registered.